# Python script generated by Postman not working

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests, postman

The below code is basically generated by Postman.  I have removed 'Content-Type' from the header as I understand that is not needed.  I've also generalised the URL path etc.  However I receive an error message:
**b'{"Message":"An error has occured. Details: Error writing MIME multipart body part to output stream."}'**

The request however does work when I run it from Postman.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests

url = "https://website.com/api/inputs/file/upload/Test/12/"

payload = {}
files = [
  ('', open('C:/Users/jmas/Documents/Demo/test.csv','rb'))
]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer 0eE6r7DWAIriN6gBR1-5WJI- 
9ZsfgE13JEthzuSXKQ9A05sbt5xdn8cAcV3Sz16D4thYNBcr6dQGdIcivSOpo- 
0dz7tAVP19trL2bwQtQez6FyzZqJFqPQrHm7fLee9eEr5GSpth0JfeqV5Gt7z_juqB3dHDBINu1oxh9G- 
pF8VuSRpUkAOujSMS0RysE1aptVqU1wAXLTXnKxUlDJLpTuQMCQGnFwqNvUWx3mDQ9xh4pw-ZaKw8TMvWaYgtmd1Z- 
oAp2IgvP9bwV5pv5izyuUWIfaZyP0mqYlZu2'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: What happens if you re-add the content type?

Comment: If I add 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to headers then I get back b'' and status code 415  (unsupported media type)

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196280/error-writing-mime-multipart-body-part-to-output-stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! I added 'text/csv' to the files parameter (dictionary) and the file successfully uploaded.

```
files = {"file": ("PremSet_2UB_0LB_NoRenewalInfo", 
open('C:/Users/jmas/Documents/Demo/test.csv', 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your payload is just an empty dictionary. Remove `data = payload`

Comment: Just tried that (with Content-Type in headers and without) and still no luck

Comment: @B.Tullero hmm, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the payload with the request, but this dictionary is empty.

I guess you need something like this:

```
url = 'https://website.com/api/inputs/file/upload/Test/12/'

files = {'': open('C:/Users/jmas/Documents/Demo/test.csv', 'rb')}

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 0eE6r7DWAIriN6gBR1-5WJI-9ZsfgE13JEthzuSXKQ9A05sbt5xdn8cAcV3Sz16D4thYNBcr6dQGdIcivSOpo -0dz7tAVP19trL2bwQtQez6FyzZqJFqPQrHm7fLee9eEr5GSpth0JfeqV5Gt7z_juqB3dHDBINu1oxh9G -pF8VuSRpUkAOujSMS0RysE1aptVqU1wAXLTXnKxUlDJLpTuQMCQGnFwqNvUWx3mDQ9xh4pw - ZaKw8TMvWaYgtmd1Z - oAp2IgvP9bwV5pv5izyuUWIfaZyP0mqYlZu2'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
print(response)
```

Your headers formatting seemed not following pep8 rules, try to change it to have it formatted well.